# Powershell: calling interactive program from a function hides output of the program. How to fix this?

Tags: function, powershell

My function:

```
Function promptYesNo($prompt) {
  & dialog --yesno $prompt 0 0
  return 1-$LastExitCode
}
```

dialog is a program, in my case taken from cygwin, which creates Text-UI dialogs (like [this](http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/images/dia3-output.jpg))

If I just call this function like this:

```
promptYesNo "Prompt"
```

Everything works as I expected. But if I try to save function's result to a variable like this:

```
$var = promptYesNo "Prompt"
```

I don't get any visible output from dialog. I mean, dialog is running, and it reacts on what I do, but I don't see it (I guess, the output is redirected somewhere).

What I do wrong and how to do it right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution to this would be to not redirect the output from the function but to return the result some other way. Here's one way that should work:

```
Function promptYesNo($prompt, [string]$varname) {
  & dialog --yesno $prompt 0 0
  Set-Variable -Name "script:$varname" -Value (1-$LastExitCode)
}

promptYesNo "Some prompt" -varname "result"
echo $result
```

The `script:` scope when setting the variable sets the variable in the caller's scope instead of the function scope.

Of course, if you do this you will have to ensure that whatever script or function you call promptYesNo from also doesn't have its output redirected, and so on out to whatever ultimately calls the code.

Comment: Nice, simple solution to the problem.  FYI Set-Variable has a scope parameter e.g. `Set-Variable -Scope Script -Name $varname -Value (1-$LastExitCode)`.  While this is a bit longer in characters there is less typing because you can use tab completion. I just love me some tab completion  :-)

Comment: @KeithHill, thanks, a numbered scope with the `-Scope` option might be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

The output is being redirected and stored in the variable.

Try looking at Tee-Object... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849937.aspx. This should allow you to capture output to a variable but still see the dialog.

I suspect the variable will contain more than you are expecting though so you may need to do some filtering.

Comment: I don't need to capture stdout of dialog at all. The only thing I need from it is exit code, which I extract using $LastExitCode.

Comment: All output generated in the function is sent down the pipeline. Try piping output of your function to out-host.

Comment: That doesn't work: it prints the whole output after dialog already finished its work.